# How to disable inertial scrolling on body for iOS browsers?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, mobile-safari

I need to **disable the inertial scrolling on the body element** for iPad, but keep the ability to scroll the page without the inertia.

I have been looking for some time but I haven't found any good solutions. Maybe I am just not looking for the right thing? Is there any hack or workaround that could make this possible?

Comment: take a look here: https://gist.github.com/amolk/1599412

Comment: Basically you will have to block the user from swiping the screen via javascript that "removes" the touchmove event. Check Monte's comment for a link.

Comment: @Monte Thanks for responding, I have updated my question to make it clearer, as I still want to be able to scroll the body, I just need to to scroll without inertia.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use div with overflow property, it kill smooth iOS scroll

```
<body>
  <div class="scroll">
    long long text...
  <div>
</body>
```

Css

```
html,
body {
 height: 100%;
 margin: 0;
 overflow: hidden;
}
.scroll {
 overflow: auto;
 height: 100%;
}
```

http://jsbin.com/palixi/edit

Comment: Note that this will mess up with the address bar behavior. Safari's address bar will not be minimized on scroll.

Answer (score 21):

Add this to the `body` element's CSS:

```
-webkit-overflow-scrolling: auto;
```

The default for `-webkit-overflow-scrolling` is `touch`. That tells iOS devices to use "inertial" scrolling. The docs: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/-webkit-overflow-scrolling

@meuwka answer achieves your goal, but in a roundabout way—it works because `div` elements have `-webkit-overflow-scrolling: auto;` as their default.

Comment: This work, but at a price. You lose the smooth scrolling.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer, while meuwka answer works.
It is only because the -webkit-overflow-scrolling defaults differently for elements that are not the body.

Comment: `webkit-overflow-scrolling` is a non-standard feature: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/-webkit-overflow-scrolling

Comment: @tgordon18 well if we're specifically targeting iOS browsers I don't think that really matters

Comment: I've tried this alone and in combination with `overflow: hidden` but I don't think this is working on iOS anymore. Tried to visualise it here: https://codepen.io/calsal/full/Exxjwwo. Scroll is disabled on desktop. On iOS Safari (by first scrolling down a bit and then up) I still get the inertia effect. Please advise if i'm wrong.

Answer (score 0):

I've used `inobounce` which can be found [here](https://github.com/lazd/iNoBounce)

You'll notice you have to specify a `height` property and `overflow: auto` to the element you'd like scrollable, including `-webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;`. The docs do a good job at explaining.

Answer (score 0):

Just setting the `-webkit-overflow-scrolling` rule to html and body doesn't work for me.

I had to set `webView.scrollView.bounces = false` in the viewDidLoad func in swift.Try it and let us know if it solves your problem.

Comment: This question isn't asking about Swift. It's about iOS web browsers.

Answer (score 0):

[iOS13 changes](https://webkit.org/blog/9674/new-webkit-features-in-safari-13/) :

### Accelerated Scrolling on iOS and iPadOS

> Accelerated scrolling the main frame has always been available with
>   WebKit on iOS. In addition, developers could use a CSS property called
>   -webkit-overflow-scrolling to opt-in to fast scrolling for overflow scroll. None of that is necessary with iPadOS and iOS 13. Subframes
>   are no longer extended to the size of their contents and are now
>   scrollable, and overflow: scroll; and iframe always get accelerated
>   scrolling. Fast scrolling emulation libraries are no longer needed and
>   -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch; is a no-op on iPad. On iPhone, it still has the side-effect of creating a CSS stacking context on
>   scrollable elements. Developers will want to test their content to see
>   how hardware accelerated scrolling everywhere affects it and remove
>   unnecessary workarounds.

Comment: `webkit-overflow-scrolling: auto` doesn't seem to do anything on iOS 13 AFAIK :-(