# overflow:hidden jumps to top in Safari

Tags: javascript, html, css

I try to achieve a scrollable lightbox without the effect of "furtherscrolling" the content behind it. So I set my html tag to "overflow:hidden" which works just fine in Chrome but not on Safari.
Any ideas how to fix this?

Answer (score 1):

Try to add position:relative to your element

Answer (score 0):

You have to disable momentum/inertia scrolling to make it work in iOS, have a look at this link. This worked for me

[How to disable inertial scrolling on body for iOS browsers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26235878/how-to-disable-inertial-scrolling-on-body-for-ios-browsers)