# -webkit-overflow-scrolling: auto; not working on touch devices

Tags: javascript, android, html, css, scroll

I'm trying to disabled the momentum/inertial scrolling on a website, it works fine on desktop but on an iPad and Android phone it doesn't work. The momentum scrolling keeps being applied.

Here is what I have in the CSS

```
-webkit-overflow-scrolling: auto;
-webkit-overflow-scrolling: auto !important;
overflow-scrolling: auto;
overflow-scrolling: auto !important;
overflow:scroll;
```

I've tried all the combination of the above but still no luck.

Is there something I'm missing here? Can it be achieved by javascript?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I found something for you:

[How to disable inertial scrolling on body for iOS browsers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26235878/how-to-disable-inertial-scrolling-on-body-for-ios-browsers)

It's just a matter of using a `<body>` wrapper, like a `<div>`, and applying `overflow: auto;` to that div. Basically Chrome for iOS is telling you "let me handle the `<body>` element, but do whatever you want with other elements.